# What is the value of $min(x,y),max(x,y)$?

Tags: functions

If $x, y$ satisfy

$$\ a \le x \le b \\$$ 
$$\ a \le y \le c$$

$w, v$ satisfy

$$\\w = max (x,y)$$
 $$\\v = min (x,y)$$
Then
$$\implies w = b, v = a$$
is this correct or not?

if it is not correct what is the answer of $\ w,v$?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are $x,y$ fixed numbers? If that's the case, then nothing can be said about the max and min. If you mean $\max \{x,y: a\leq x \leq b, a\leq y \leq c\}$ then @Sanwar is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$w=\max(b,c)$ and your answer for $v$ is correct.

Comment: $\ w = max(b,c) $ 
does this mean $\ w$ could be b or c?

Comment: it depends on which is larger. Your question doesn't give enough information to get the concrete answer you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

The implication cannot be made for the max, but for the minimum you are correct.

Also, you take the max and min of a *set*, not of a list (you seem to have an ordered pair).